# iPhone SDK Objective-C __DATE__ (compile date) can't be converted to an NSDate

Tags: iphone, date, compilation, nsdate, nsdateformatter

```
//NSString *compileDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", __DATE__];
NSString *compileDate = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:__DATE__];

NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

[df setDateFormat:@"MMM d yyyy"];   
//[df setDateFormat:@"MMM dd yyyy"];    

NSDate *aDate = [df dateFromString:compileDate];
```

Ok, I give up.  Why would aDate sometimes return as nil?

Should it matter if I use the commented-out lines... or their matching replacement lines?

Comment: small note not worth an answer: due to the way the preprocessor works, to get __DATE__ as an NSString you can simply write @__DATE__

Answer (score 22):

It can return nil if the phone's Region setting is not US (or equivalent).

Try setting the formatter's locale to en_US:

```
NSString *compileDate = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:__DATE__];
NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[df setDateFormat:@"MMM d yyyy"];
NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[df setLocale:usLocale];
[usLocale release];
NSDate *aDate = [df dateFromString:compileDate];
```

Comment: Wow.  I'll try that.
 
I thought __DATE__ would always be determined during compile-time... and based on the machine I was compiling it on (English).
  
So __DATE__ would *ALWAYS* be in "Feb 1 2010" format.

(I'm not asking for the date to be determined during run-time... or based on the user's local setting.)

Comment: The `__DATE__` macro is determined at compile time and replaced with a string literal in that format.  But your conversion of that string into an NSDate happens at run-time which is affected by the current region.

Answer (score 9):

Slightly modifying DyingCactus' answer for ARC enabled code (for easier copying-n-pasting):

```
NSString *compileDate = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:__DATE__];
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"MMM d yyyy"];
NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[df setLocale:usLocale];
NSDate *aDate = [df dateFromString:compileDate];
```