# Build information in iOS Application (date/time app was built)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, build-process

I'm looking for a way to dynamically add in information about the application during the build process of an iOS application.

During testing, it would be great to know when the application I have installed on my device was built and possibly who built it would be a good to know as well.

I'm envisioning a section in settings.app that would give basic build information for debugging purposes. I don't want to have to manually update a build information file before each build - the data should be generated dynamically.

Comment: These similar questions might provide some ideas for how to stamp values into files at build time: [Insert Subversion revision number in Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372218/insert-subversion-revision-number-in-xcode) and [How can I display the application version revision in my application's settings bundle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/877128/how-can-i-display-the-application-version-revision-in-my-applications-settings-b)

Comment: Thanks Brad, those are great resources.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write a shell script build phase in Xcode that runs at the end of your build process. In this phase you can use the `defaults` command to write data to an arbitrary file. I've used this technique to write to the Info.plist file, but you can write to any file you want[1].

Here's a sample script to write the current git version to Info.plist:

```
infoplist="$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$INFOPLIST_PATH"
gitversion="$(cd "$SRCROOT" && git describe --always --dirty 2>/dev/null)"
if [[ -n "$gitversion" ]]; then
    defaults write "${infoplist%.plist}" GitVersion "$gitversion"
fi
```

You should be able to adapt this to point to the file you want (e.g. your Settings bundle) and write the info you want.

[1] Be careful if you write to Info.plist, Xcode has bugs that can prevent it from realizing Info.plist changed during the build, which can break the provisioning when doing a device build.

Comment: Terrific idea, however... I do this to save a key BuildDateTime. I can read [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"BuildDateTime"] fine in the simulator, but when I build for AdHoc distribution, and load the app on a device, [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"BuildDateTime"] returns null. Any ideas?

Comment: @mputnamtennessee: Have you tried opening up your ad-hoc build and checking the Info.plist by hand?

Answer (score 13):

You can also use standard macro `__DATE__` which will result string like "Jun 25 1980" of course with proper current date of build.

Comment: This is the way to go here.

Comment: In order to transform that __DATE__ macro to a NSString check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862469/iphone-sdk-objective-c-date-compile-date-cant-be-converted-to-an-nsdate

Comment: You can also use the `__TIME__` macro to add the time to the date.