# xcode after update app-info.plist only the old information available in the app

Tags: xcode, build, version, plist

through a custom script i update my CFBundleVersion in my app-info.plist when I build and run the app. This information is used as well in the app to display the app name and version. The update works fine in the build process, but the unfortunatly the old information is read in the app itself.

E.g. When I build and run the app the app-info.plist is updated, the `CFBundleVersion` has now the value `8`, but in the simulator the value `7` is shown.

Seems so that the updated app-info.plist is not used in the build process, instead the old version is used.

How can I ensure that the updated app-info.plist is used in my app? 
On the one hand somehow the execution of the script should be the first thing in the build-process or on the other hand the app-info.plist should be renewed in the build process. But for both I do not know how to do this...

I added the custom script under Project > Buildphases > Add Build Phase > Add Run Script. With the following contents:

```
shell: /bin/bash   Tools/addVersionNumber.sh
```

### Tools/addVersionNumber.sh -> works like desired

```sh
#/bin/bash
# script that should be executed in the build phase
# to set the build number correct

plist="app-folder/app-Info.plist"

## get git information 
# git_rev_full_hash=$( git rev-parse HEAD )
git_amount_commits=$( git rev-list HEAD | wc -l )
git_rev_short_hash=$( git rev-parse --short HEAD )
buildRevision="$git_amount_commits: $git_rev_short_hash"

# set build revision ( git short hash - amount of commits )
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :BuildRevision $buildRevision" $plist""

## build number
buildNumber=$( /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" $plist ) 
buildNumber=$(( $buildNumber + 1 ))

# set new build number
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" $plist
```

cheers -- jerik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution. The trick was that the info.plist in the build folder and the plist in dsym (?) has to be updated as well.

My runscript looks now like this

```sh
#/bin/bash
# script that should be executed in the build phase
# to set the build number correct
#
# http://www.cimgf.com/2008/04/13/git-and-xcode-a-git-build-number-script/
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944185/how-to-get-xcode-to-add-build-date-time-to-info-plist-file
# http://www.danandcheryl.com/2012/10/automatic-build-numbers-for-ios-apps-using-xcode

# Marketing Number is in CFBundleShortVersionString - will be edited manually
# @TODO add logging 

plist="app-folder/app-Info.plist"
build_plist=$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$INFOPLIST_PATH
conInfo="Contents/Info.plist"
dsym_plist=$DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH/$DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME/$conInfo

function writePlist( ) { 

    # set build revision ( git short hash - amount of commits )
    /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :BuildRevision $buildRevision" $1

    # set build date
    /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :BuildDate $buildDate" $1

    #set build number
    /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" $1
}

# git_rev_full_hash=$( git rev-parse HEAD )
buildRevision=$( git rev-parse --short HEAD )
git_rev_plist_hash=$( /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print BuildRevision" $plist )

# Only update version if a commit was performed. Avoid update version when in development cycle
if [[ $git_rev_plist_hash != $buildRevision ]]; then

    ### variables for updating plist
    # set new build number and date
    buildNumber=$( /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" $plist ) 
    buildNumber=$(( $buildNumber + 1 ))
    buildDate=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %T %z %Z")

    writePlist $plist
    writePlist $build_plist
    writePlist $dsym_plist

fi
```

cheers -- jerik

Comment: This seems like a complete hack ... but it works!  Thanks.  BTW, since you found your own answer, I think it's acceptable around here to mark your own answer as accepted.