# Programmatically get iPhone activation date

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Is there any way to find the iPhone Manufacturing date ,first app being installed on iPhone date programmatically, ,i search a lot but could not able to get it .Need someone to help me out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build information in iOS Application (date/time app was built)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855281/build-information-in-ios-application-date-time-app-was-built)

Comment: Sounds like the kind of things you wouldn't need to know, according to Apple. And, to be frank, according to me as well. Why would you need to know, out of curiosity?

Comment: @Morpheu5 I ,just want to know the Feasibility and if apple doesn't support also okay

Comment: I suppose if you jailbroke the phone and got root access, you could probably find something.