# datefromstring always return nil on physical device objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdateformatter

I have to show app build date in the project. In `"dd MMM yyyy"` format.

```objc
GetBuildDate {
    NSString *buildDate;

    // Get build date and time, format to 'yyMMddHHmm'
    NSString *dateStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:__DATE__], [NSString stringWithUTF8String:__TIME__]];

    // Convert to date
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"LLL d yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];

    // Set output format and convert to string
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy"];
    buildDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];

    

    return buildDate;
}
```

The above code works fine on a simulator but returns `nil` on a physical device.
I tried setting  the timezone and locale on the device, but to no avail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iPhone SDK Objective-C \_\_DATE\_\_ (compile date) can't be converted to an NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862469/iphone-sdk-objective-c-date-compile-date-cant-be-converted-to-an-nsdate)

Comment: How did you try adding the timezone and locale? Please add what you tried to your question.

Comment: [dateFormat setLocale: [NSLocale systemLocal]  ]; gives the same nil value for the date. I donot want to add specific location as it should take iPhone locale such as singapore . Any suggestions

Comment: Quick question: In the iPhone, what's the user preferences for the date? I would guess that the user prefers 12h format, or might use an other calendar?

Comment: @Ruhi did you read the duplicate question? `__DATE__` is not of the system locale, it must be read with `en`-compatible locale. You have to set it for your formatter like that `dateFormat.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];`

Comment: `Locale` != `location`. Set the **Locale** to generic `en_US_POSIX` for a fixed date format. Please read https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1480/_index.html